# Perfectly round a number in PHP

Tags: php, html

So, i retrieved with an API a number, which is `1441971834999104426`.
I would like to round it to `1441971835`

However, when i do : `round(1441971834999104426, -9);` the output is : `1.441971835E+18`, which is not what i want at all.

Can you give me some advices on how I can do the rounding perfectly?

Thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the number by `1e9`, and round that.

```
echo round(1441971834999104426/1e9);
```